# Ldap change password

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

hello I would like to make users change the password of the accounts without receiving the email since it is an internal server how can I change the password of ldap with laravel and php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use the laravel/ldap package. This will do everything you need to do working with LDAP.
https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel

With this package you can do auth grab user info from ldap and change ldap info. This package is based on PHP ldap and ported over to Laravel.